# Send email using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting this an error when I am trying to send an email/read my details using microsoft graph.

This is the error : "AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'myThumbprint', Found key 'Start=10/02/2022 18:06:49, End=10/02/2027 18:06:49', Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'"
Code:

```
       {
        logger.LogInformation("Loading files from drop point. Function executed at: {Date}", DateTime.Now);
        string message;
        using var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
            "myThumbprint",
            false);

        if (certCollection.Count == 0)
        {
            message = "Could not find an installed certificate " +
                             $"with the with a matching Thumbprint to ";
            logger.LogError(message);
        }

        X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
        logger.LogInformation(cert.FriendlyName);
        string tenantId = "";
        string clientId = "";
        string clietnIdCertificate = "";

        var credential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, cert);
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential,scopes);


        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clietnIdCertificate)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithCertificate(cert)
            .Build();

        var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication
                        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

        string incomingToken = authResult.AccessToken.ToString();

        TokenProvider provider = new TokenProvider();
        var onBehalf = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId,clientId,cert,incomingToken);
        provider.token = incomingToken;
        var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(provider);
        var graphServiceClient2 = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalf,scopes);
        var user = await graphServiceClient2.Me.GetAsync();

    }
    public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(token);
        }

        public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
    }
```

My azure configuration :
[image]